# How to allign dynamic list item in RadioButtonList VB

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have created a radiobuttonlist which items in it are generated dynamically based on my database. And I'm using VB webform.

**IN HTML:**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlSession" runat="server" CssClass="rdl">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**VB:**

```
For count = 0 To someitem.Length 'databaseitem
        With rdlSession.Items
            .Add(someitem)
        End With
Next
```

[image]

**My question is:**
How to align the rows to start from the red line ?

(I have tried using text-allign:left,but the output doesnt affect much, the first line appears after the radiobutton.)

Comment: Apply a css class to radio buttons and do it with css.

Comment: yes, i have tried, but the first row which has the radio button at front will ruin the whole allignment @MairajAhmad

Comment: You want every radio button on new line ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Nope, i want the four rows of words to be parallel to the red line i placed, which means every row will starts after the redline

Answer (score 1):

You need `css` to solve that problem.

`RadioButtonList` is (if You see `Page Source`) `table` with `rows` where are `RadioButtons` placed.

For example, 1st item of `RadioButtonList` in `html` will be (two "elements" : one is `<input type="radio" id="rdlSession_0" ...>` and `label` for that `input`) :

```
<input id="rdlSession_0" type="radio" name="rdlSession" value="Session :0&lt;br>Date :0&lt;br>Coach :0&lt;br>Available slot :0" /><label for="rdlSession_0">Session :0<br>Date :0<br>Coach :0<br>Available slot :0</label>
```

You need to apply some `css` for that `label`.

**HTML**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlSession" runat="server" CssClass="rdl">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**CSS**

```
.rdl label
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

If You remove `vertical-align:top;`, radio button will be aligned at bottom.

I hope so this solution will work for You.